# Book about a space traveler who meets a cat-like alien on another planet

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, telepathy

I read this around 10 years ago and it was an old book I bought from the school library. It was maybe around 200-300 pages and not a large book. I read it when I was young, so I don't remember everything. What I do know is:

- The traveler was a man.
- The cat was large (think panther), a female, and maybe colorful.
- The cat could also speak telepathically to the man, however, the man could not hear that the cat was female.
- Further in in the book, the cat realizes that she's pregnant, and after a while, so does the man (which makes him realize it's a female).
- On the planet, quite often, a sand storm rages on, so they have to hide in holes.
- The cat was either banished from her home town or she ran away.

Sadly, I don't remember anything more about the plot.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year or decade did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall any details about the cover?

Comment: I read it around 10 years ago and it was an old book I bought from the school library. It's maybe around 200-300 pages and not a large book

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. If anyone correctly identifies the book you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Thank u! Will do!

Comment: @DannyMcG Your memory sounds like "Blind lightning" by Harlan Ellison

Comment: Is this "cat-like alien" a bipedal, feline humanoid or an intelligent, quadrupedal dat-line being? Did the alien get pregnant before meeting the space traveller or while travelling with him?

Comment: The latter and before. She got pregnant by another one of her kind

Comment: Could this be "Exiles of the Start" by Andre Norton? It matches on 3 or 4 of the points but not others. It has two protagonists who communicate by ESP. One of them is a human mind inside a humanoid alien body, and his companion was a  woman and priestess on a planet where the priesthood was adept at body switching and now inhabits the form of a small four footed hunting animal. They are traveling together as the woman has been banished. Don't recall her getting pregnant though., they land on a planet where the native, apparently extinct, civilization used a cat motiff.

Comment: @user8485927 I remember Exiles of the Stars. You're right, she didn't get pregnant, and she was in her original body when she first met the human in the previous book (so her sex wasn't a surprise).  A telepathic cat-like alien is very Andre Norton, though.

Answer (score 1):

The sand storm element remins me of "Day of the Starwind" - the protagonist has an alien companion but if I remember right she's more bat than cat.  It's a fairly short YA book.  Our hero has unbreakable bones a la Wolverine, if that sounds familiar?

Comment: Sadly, that's not the book, but it did make me remember a detail: the man and the feline met each other on the (alien) planet and for some reason they decided to travel together

Answer (score -1):

Murdoc Jern series
Book 1 Zero Stone
Book 2 Uncharted Stars
Author: Andre Norton.

Comment: Can you add some description of those books that shows how they match the question?

Comment: Note that Eet is cat-sized, not panther-sized, and it is the ship's cat Valcyr, not Eet, that is "pregnant."

Comment: Obviously not. As you already know I commented before saying I was looking for the same book. I found the answer and shared here.

Comment: Also eet is clearly not cat size. Eet is panther size.

Comment: "With Eet warm and heavy about my shoulders, and the future, misty and threatened as it was, before me, I left the cabin to walk into a new slice of life." Eet is small enough to ride on Jern's shoulders.  Not a panther.

Comment: You're kidding right? The cover of the book IS LITERALLY A BLACK PANTHER!

Comment: You mean you didn't know that [Covers Always Lie](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CoversAlwaysLie)?  Those 1980s Ace covers are _notably_ bad; look at the cover for [*Moon of Three Rings*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?944416) or [*Galactic Derelict*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?943675).  For comparison, check out the [other covers of *The Zero Stone*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?2951).  The Ace cover of [*Uncharted Stars*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?145924) does get Eet right though.

Comment: @JohnDollar Do not insult other users. It is not harassment or trolling for other users to criticize your answer in the comments in an attempt to improve it.

Comment: It wasn't an insult. It was a criticism.